# Simple threading at Rails database connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this is just a sample code snippet for tryout. the problem is that rails rolls back the transaction. the problematic part is that **create** / the db transaction is executed in a thread. addendum/ detour: should i use sidekiq or something? I don't know much about that, yet.

```
t=Thread.new do
   sleep 0
   Timeticket.create(item_id:1, time:10)
   sleep 60
end
t.join
puts "thread ended"
```

Comment: i updated the question. thanks

Comment: I am sorry, perhaps it is just me, but your question is still not clear to me.  _the problem is that rails rolls back the transaction._ Yes Rails does that in certain situations (mostly if there is an error). Did you investigate why Rails rolls back? Why is that a problem to you? What do you try to achieve? Avoid the error that triggers the roll back? Write to the database even if there is an error?

Comment: the problem is that rails always rolls back the transaction when i execute a create or update within a thread ...

Comment: And does Rails tell you why it does that? Is there a failing validation? Some message in the log file? An error message with a stacktrace?

Comment: Note you might need to replace `create` with `create!` to get a more verbose error message.